# Explode HTML form to CSV with PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I have a project that requires form input to be saved as a CSV but I have the option of using the CSV as a file to be handled and imported to a local database table. The form is already populated from excel sheets or CSV files, and then the user can edit or add to the form. I have the php set up to insert into the table with the right columns, I'm just trying to find the best way to save this form, even if it has multiple rows, as a full CSV file that I can use as a handle when the submit button is triggered.

This code creates the form from the file initially:

```
?><form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"><?
    echo '<table>';

    /*WE WILL NEED TO QA CONDITIONS AND HIGHLIGHT IN RED HERE. ALSO NEED BORDER STYLINGS*/

    if ($hasHeaderRow) {
        $headerRow = fgetcsv($handle);
        echo '<thead><tr>';
        foreach($headerRow as $value) {
            echo "<th>$value</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr></thead>';
    }

    echo '<tbody>';

    $rowCount = 0;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value) {
            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"$value\"></td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';

        if (++$rowCount > $maxPreviewRows) {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';

}
?>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" >Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way to explode this into a CSV since I don't declare each field?

Comment: for a start your inputs need names, then you ould loop\implode in to a csv file

Comment: That's my issue currently, the initial file has hundreds of fields so this form just turns each field into an input box.  Isn't there a way to just iterate through the td values

Comment: there would be if you gae your inputs names, then they would be stored in the get\post array on submit

Comment: Oh see that's where I wasn't sure. The original uploaded file has 5 rows, each with 200 fields so it's a huge form in this instance

Comment: Would there be a better solution since this preview table form has so many input fields? Or would I have to create a field name for all 200 on the first row and then loop it?

Comment: `name="foo[]"` will create an array named foo you can then loop, you can go a step further as you already have a row count and use `foo[$rowCount][]` then you will have a nested array set to loop through\implode

Comment: I think I understand, but would that alleviate the issue with naming the inputs? Or would I have to name them in the loop?

Comment: they would all have the same name. just add `name="foo[]"` to the code above then `print_r($_POST);` on submit;  and you will see what have to work with

Comment: I see what you mean. That creates my array from the first row then I can loop for the other rows and explode that to the database from there

Comment: Thanks a lot, this gets me on the right track!

Comment: @nogad i tired this but it;s not quite working. I altered my code like this:  foreach($row as $value) {
          echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"$value\" name=\"foo[$rowCount][]\"></td>";
      }
However, print_r($_POST) doesn't print it because I have an if statement before the code that responds to a preview button so it prints an array that just says preview (the name of my button)